# Reset Windows Bluetooth name cache

Tags: windows, caching, bluetooth, reset

how do I reset Windows' Bluetooth name cache. I am conducting experiments with home-brew BT hardware and right now I need Windows to display the current name of the device. I discovered that I can rename the device in Windows. This changes only the name cache. However, Windows now seems to only use the name cache. It no longer shows the current name of the device. Now I need to find a way to clear the cache. I searched the registry, but to no avail. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you asking about a programmatic way to reset?

Comment: I just need it for testing purposes. If it can be done manually (regedit), this would be totally fine.

Comment: Have you had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964685/how-do-i-totally-delete-reset-bluetooth-settings-in-windows-7)?

Comment: You mean wildly deleting registry keys?

Comment: The method listed there is, to my knowledge, the only publicly documented method... However, I'm not in any way an expert in this area, so I might be wrong on this

Comment: I scanned the keys and subkeys and I did not find any sign of the device's name. Not in clear text nor in binary. If the device is installed, I can find a subkey with its UID. But this key gets deleted when I uninstall the device.
So I doubt deleting the keys will work and I cannot risk trashing my system at the moment.